# Excel 2013/2016 macro Error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a macro to save a range from a Worksheet to a PDF file. When I run the macro it gives an error:

> Error 1004 during execution application-defined or object-defined
>   error

I noticed that when I remove `J109:Y157,Z158:AS187` from ranges that it works. When I try that range instead of the rest it works fine. It just doesn't work when they are together in ranges.

The area that gets highlighted is:

```
Sheets("JSA-CE NTR klapbordessen").Range(ranges).ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        FileName:=CurrentFolder & FileName & ".pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

This is the code:

```
Sub Range_to_PDF()

Dim ranges As String
Dim CurrentFolder As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim myPath As String


'Informatie over Excel bestand
myPath = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
CurrentFolder = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
FileName = Mid(myPath, InStrRev(myPath, "\") + 1, _
InStrRev(myPath, ".") - InStrRev(myPath, "\") - 1)

'Gebied voor PDF
ranges = ("A42:H108,J109:Y157,Z158:AS187,AT187:BC235,AT237:BC285,AT287:BC335,AT337:BC385,AT387:BC435,AT437:BC485,AT487:BC535,AT537:BC585,AT587:BC635,AT637:BC685,AT687:BC735,AT737:BC785,AT787:BC835,AT837:BC885,AT887:BC935," & _
            "AT937:BC985,AT987:BC1035,AT1037:BC1085,AT1087:BC1135,AT1137:BC1185")

'Controle of er al een bestand met dezelfde naam is
Do While UniqueName = False
    DirFile = CurrentFolder & FileName & ".pdf"

    If Len(Dir(DirFile)) <> 0 Then
      UserAnswer = MsgBox("Bestand bestaat al! Klik " & _
       "[Ja] om te overschrijven. Klik [Nee] om te hernoemen.", vbYesNoCancel)

      If UserAnswer = vbYes Then
        UniqueName = True
      ElseIf UserAnswer = vbNo Then
        Do
          'Retrieve New File Name
            FileName = Application.InputBox("Geef een nieuwe bestandsnaam " & _
             "(Vraagt opnieuw als het een verkeerde bestandsnaam is)", , _
             FileName, Type:=2)

          'Exit if User Wants To
            If FileName = "False" Or FileName = "" Then Exit Sub
        Loop While ValidFileName(FileName) = False
      Else
        Exit Sub 'Cancel
      End If
    Else
      UniqueName = True
    End If
  Loop

'Aanpassen aan pagina formaat
With Worksheets("JSA-CE NTR klapbordessen").PageSetup
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 1
End With


'Opslaan van PDF
Sheets("JSA-CE NTR klapbordessen").Range(ranges).ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        FileName:=CurrentFolder & FileName & ".pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True

'Deactiveer pagina onderbreking
  ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
  ActiveSheet.Select

'Bevestig opslaan aan gebruiker
  With ActiveWorkbook
    FolderName = Mid(.Path, InStrRev(.Path, "\") + 1, Len(.Path) - InStrRev(.Path, "\"))
  End With

  MsgBox "PDF opgeslagen in de map: " & CurrentFolder

Exit Sub

'Error Handlers
ProblemSaving:
  MsgBox "Er was een probleem met het opslaan van de PDF. Dit is vaak" & _
   " doordat het originele PDF bestand al open is."
  Exit Sub

End Sub

Function ValidFileName(FileName As String) As Boolean

Dim TempPath As String
Dim wb As Workbook

'Determine Folder Where Temporary Files Are Stored
  TempPath = Environ("TEMP")

'Create a Temporary XLS file (XLS in case there are macros)
  On Error GoTo InvalidFileName
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(ActiveWorkbook.TempPath & _
     "\" & FileName & ".xls", xlExcel8)
  On Error Resume Next

'Delete Temp File
  Kill wb.FullName

'File Name is Valid
  ValidFileName = True

Exit Function

'ERROR HANDLERS
InvalidFileName:
  'File Name is Invalid
    ValidFileName = False

End Function
```

Also when I choose to change the file name and click after that on Cancel in that box I get an error saying:

> Compile error: expected function or variable

This is in the function part. The highlighted area is the first line of the function (Funtion ValidFileName etc.).

I'm not an expert in coding and honestly I have no idea what could be wrong. I tried to Google the error but I don't understand how to apply those solutions to my code. This code is also a mix from a few websites put together.

Comment: It would also be helpful to know which lines get highlighted when you get the errors. Could you please update your question with that information?

Comment: I tried the macro on a empty Excel file but it highlights the same area.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe `SaveAs` returns an object. Try removing `Set wb =` from that line and then also remove this `Kill wb.FullName`

If you really do want to still delete it, do it like this instead:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Kill ActiveWorkbook.FullName
```

Comment: If I remove `Set wb =` I get an error: "Compile error: expected: =".